# Logstash [aggregate filter] to pass data between events

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, elk, logstash-filter

i am currently working on a project with the Elastic stack for a log monitoring system. The logs i have to load are in a specific format so i have to write my own logstash scripts to read them. In particular one type of logs where i have a date in the start of the file and the timestamp in each of the other lines has no date, my goal is to extract the date from the first line and add it to all the next ones, after some research i found that the aggregate filter can help but i can't get it to work, here is my config file :

```
input
{
    file {
        path => "F:/ELK/data/testFile.txt"
        #path => "F:/ELK/data/*/request/*"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "NUL"
    }
}
filter
{
    mutate {
        add_field => { "taskId" => "all" }
    }

        grok
        {
            match => {"message" => "-- %{NOTSPACE} %{NOTSPACE}: %{DAY}, %{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY:day}, %{YEAR:year}%{GREEDYDATA}"}
            tag_on_failure => ["not_date_line"]
        }

        
    
    if "not_date_line" not in [tags]
    {
        mutate{
            replace => {'taskId' => "%{day}/%{month}/%{year}"}
            remove_field => ["day","month","year"]
        }

        aggregate
        {
            task_id => "%{taskId}"
            code => "map['taskId'] = event.get('taskId')"
            map_action => "create"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dissect
        {
            mapping => { message => "%{sequence_index}  %{time} %{pid}  %{puid} %{stack_level}  %{operation}    %{params}   %{op_type}  %{form_event}   %{op_duration}"}
        }

        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{taskId}"
            code => "event.set('taskId', map['taskId'])"
            map_action => "update"
            timeout => 0
        }
        mutate
        {
            strip => ["op_duration"]
            replace => {"time" => "%{taskId}-%{time}"}
        }
    }
    
    mutate
    {
        remove_field => ['@timestamp','host','@version','path','message','tags']
    }
}
output 
{
    stdout{}
}
```

the scripts reads the date correctly but then doesn't work to replace the value in the other events :

```
{
    "taskId" => "22/October/2020"
}
{
               "pid" => "45",
    "sequence_index" => "10853799",
           "op_type" => "1",
              "time" => "all-16:23:29:629",
            "params" => "90",
       "stack_level" => "0",
       "op_duration" => "",
         "operation" => "10",
        "form_event" => "0",
            "taskId" => "all",
              "puid" => "1724"
}
```

I am using only one worker to ensure the order of the events is kept intact , if you know of any other way to achieve this i'm open to suggestions, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Badger and some other post he answered on the elastic forum, i found a solution using a single ruby filter and an instance variable, couldn't get it to work with the aggregate filter but that is not an issue for me.

```
ruby
{
    init => '@date = ""'
    code => "
        event.set('date',@date) unless @date.empty?
        @date = event.get('date') unless event.get('date').empty?
    "
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the lines which have a date you are setting the taskId to "%{day}/%{month}/%{year}", for the rest of the lines you are setting it to "all". The aggregate filter will not aggregate across events with different task ids.

I suggest you use a constant taskId and store the date in some other field, then in a single aggregate filter you can use something like

```
code => '
    date = event.get("date")
    if date
        @date = date
    else
        event.set("date", @date)
    end
'
```

@date is an instance variable, so its scope is limited to that aggregate filter, but it is preserved across events. It is not shared with other aggregate filters (that would require a class variable or a global variable).

Note that you require event order to be preserved, so you should set pipeline.workers to 1.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer ! i got the first part and thank you for the clarification, but to be honnest i don't know how to go about the rest, i tried adding a new filed the result is it gets populated for my first line with the date and it's empty for the rest.
i don't really understand the logic of the filter and the documentation is not helping
edit : i have 0 ruby knowledge , i think the @date is for global variable but i'm not sure

Comment: @date is an instance variable, not a global variable. It exists within that specific aggregate filter (not shared across filters) but is shared across events. That is why I said to use a single aggregate. The logic of the code is "If the [date] field exists then save its value, otherwise set the [date] field to the saved value."

Comment: i can't get it to work, i think my issue is with writing the variable if i do a replace on the new field "date"  it doesn't work (it works for my first event then nothing), maybe doing it differently ?